# Rewriting quadratic form using coordinate transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I just finished a linear algebra exam and I could answer most of it except for the bonus question.

From memory, it looked something like this:

> $x_1^2 - x_3^2 - 4x_1x_2 + 4x_2x_3$ can be written as $-3y_2^2 + 3y_3^2$ using a well chosen coordinate transformation. Show it without actually doing that transformation, and afterwards with the transformation.

I've tried doing a transformation, but you're supposed to be able to do this without doing one. I am lost. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix for the quadratic form is $$\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&0\\-2&0&2\\0&2&-1\end{bmatrix}$$ Its characteristic equation is $$(1-\lambda)(-\lambda)(-1-\lambda)-4(1-\lambda)+4(1+\lambda)=\lambda-\lambda^3-4+4\lambda +4+4\lambda=-(\lambda^3-9\lambda)$$ so the eigenvalues are 0, +3 and -3. Under the orthogonal change of basis (which will exist because the matrix is symmetric), you would get the diagonal matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&-3\end{bmatrix}$$ which corresponds to the quadratic form $$3y_2^2-3y_3^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the intent of the question was to complete the square:
$$x_1^2- x_3^2- 4x_1x_2 + 4x_2x_3=(x_1-2x_2)^2-(x_3-2x_2)^2$$
and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Just show that the eigenvalues match. Because of symmetry, the eigenvectors are always orthogonal. You can find eigenvalues without actually finding the coordinate frame $y_2$ and $y_3$.